# Wagtail Blog example results in no attribute '_default_manager'

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail

I'm working through the [wagtail tutorial.](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/getting_started/tutorial.html) Using Python 3.6.7, Wagtail 2.5.1, Django 2.2.1.  Everything works until I get to adding the **categories** near the end of the page ...

```
class ArticlePage(Page):
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    intro = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through=ArticlePageTag, blank=True)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('article.ArticleCategory', blank=True)

# ... (Keep the main_image method and search_fields definition)

content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
    MultiFieldPanel([
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('tags'),
        FieldPanel('categories', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
    ], heading="Article information"),
    FieldPanel('intro'),
    FieldPanel('body'),
    InlinePanel('gallery_images', label="Gallery images"),
]
```

The FieldPanel "categories" produces an error.  Here is the Traceback when running makemigrations :

```
(env) simon@ckweb$ ./manage.py makemigrations                                                                                                                    │Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                                               │Exception in thread django-main-thread:
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>                                                                                                                       │Traceback (most recent call last):
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)                                                                                                                          │  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line                               │    self.run()
    utility.execute()                                                                                                                                            │  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute                                                 │    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)                                                                                                      │  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv                                               │    fn(*args, **kwargs)
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)                                                                                                                           │  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in execute                                                     │    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
    self.check()                                                                                                                                                 │  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check                                                       │    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,                                                                                                         │  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks                                                 │    fn(*args, **kwargs)
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)                                                                                                                           │  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks                                                   │    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)                                                                                                                  │  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/checks.py", line 63, in get_form_class_check                                                │    app_config.import_models()
    if not issubclass(edit_handler.get_form_class(), WagtailAdminPageForm):                                                                                      │  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py", line 369, in get_form_class                                              │    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
    widgets=self.widget_overrides())                                                                                                                             │  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py", line 64, in get_form_for_model                                           │    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    return metaclass(class_name, (form_class,), form_class_attrs)                                                                                                │  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/forms/models.py", line 66, in __new__                                                       │  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
    new_class = super(WagtailAdminModelFormMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)                                                                      │  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/modelcluster/forms.py", line 245, in __new__                                                              │  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
    new_class = super(ClusterFormMetaclass, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)                                                                                │  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 256, in __new__                                                             │  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    apply_limit_choices_to=False,                                                                                                                                │  File "/mnt/c/Users/simon/OneDrive/dev/wagtail/ckweb/articles/models.py", line 33, in <module>
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/forms/models.py", line 176, in fields_for_model                                                    │    class ArticlePage(Page):
    formfield = formfield_callback(f, **kwargs)                                                                                                                  │  File "/mnt/c/Users/simon/OneDrive/dev/wagtail/ckweb/articles/models.py", line 58, in ArticlePage
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/forms/models.py", line 47, in formfield_for_dbfield                                         │    InlinePanel('related_content_page', widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
    return db_field.formfield(**kwargs)                                                                                                                          │  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py", line 646, in __init__
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 1626, in formfield                                              │    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    'queryset': self.remote_field.model._default_manager.using(using),                                                                                           │TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'widget'
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_default_manager'
```

Commenting out **FieldPanel** and **categories** lines removes the error.  I believe it is related to the "ParentalManyToManyField".  I have a couple of Categories defined through the wagtail UI

The [source is on GitHub](https://github.com/inyoka/ckweb.git), although the App is called **Articles**, rather than **Blog** used in the example. Sure I am missing something simple but cant see it for the life of me.  Any help gratefully received.

Comment: `categories = ParentalManyToManyField('article.ArticleCategory', blank=True)`
#
You mean error is raised after add this line ?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: error is raised when view is called ? or during migrations ? because `_default manager` is same as `objects()` attribute which is instance of `Manager`. `print(Model._default_manager is Model.objects) # returns True`

Comment: Commenting out the categories field and fieldpanel immediately generates the error. After that, running makemigrations also generates the same error.

Comment: Is your app called article or articles? If your ArticleCategory model is defined before ArticlePage you can use the class name. No string. ParentalManyToManyField(ArticleCategory, ...)

Comment: Or if your app name is articleS: 'article.ArticleCategory' -> 'articles.ArticleCategory'

Comment: Thank you! That was it 'article.ArticleCategory' -> 'articles.ArticleCategory', such a maddeningly simple answer.  If you add it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relation is referenced by `app_name.ModelName`. In your case the app name is `articles` (plural).

Change:

```
ParentalManyToManyField('article.ArticleCategory', blank=True)
```

To

```
ParentalManyToManyField('articles.ArticleCategory', blank=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, while this was a simple problem the error was vague, hopefully it'll help someone in the future.